# How to connect an existing SQL Server database on a remote server using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: sql-server, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How can I connect my application to an existing `SQL Server` database that is on a remote server using `Xamarin.Forms`?

Comment: Directly accessing a database server from a remote client of any sort is a horrible security risk.  The recommended approach is generally to use a webservice layer between your client and your database.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do that , 
I think the proper way to do this is by exposing an API service on that remote server which has an access to the database . Then you can connect the app to that service using Resful calls .

Comment: Do you mean, I should to request to load an API service on the server? Okey I will ask this to my host... :/

Comment: I meant you deal with it like any Client/serverr application . The server provides and the client consumes